# It is bad to sign in a company while you are waiting to another to call you, and then leave it?

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process, hiring, first-job

I was unemployed about 3 months, and I send my information a lot of companies. 
I was interested in one in particular, here called as A company, but the never reply my emails. After a certain time I was contacted by, B company, the work and the project in company was good, and I was hoping them to hire me, but they take their time. Meanwhile, finally Company A contact me, and I was very happy, and the work and all the other benefits were greater than company B, I still in selection process but HR said I'm a very good candidate, and that the process take time. 
The company B, finally select me as the one whom they want, but now, I don't want to lose my chance to get in company A. 
But anyway I'm afraid that I don't get in company A, for some reason. 
And I was thinking to sign with company B, as backup plan, but that doesn't feel good. I don't know what to do. 
What can I do?

Answer (score 10):

You don't have a job offer with "A"

You have one with "B"

Tell "A" that you have an offer on the table, but would rather work for them.

"A" will do one of three things.

1. Say Yes
2. Say No
3. Neither (by either stalling "we'll get back to you" or by not responding.)

Unless you get a "YES" from "A" you go with "B"

Comment: That's an excellent overview of the steps!